# Static/Final java classes?

Tags: java, singleton, instance-variables

I want to force implementation of the singleton pattern on any of the extended classes of my parent class. That is, I only want one instance of every child class to ever be around (accessible through Child.INSTANCE or something like this).

Ideally what I would like would be for the Child.INSTANCE object to be made, and then no other object of type Parent to be made.

Currently I get my instances through something like:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public static final Child INSTANCE = new Child();
    ....
```

I wonder, can a java class be made static or something in some way?

Thanks =]

Comment: To answer one part of the question:  inner classes can be made static;  as far as the rest of the question, I'm not entirely sure if what you're looking for can be done

Comment: Are you trying to have a single instance of EACH class in the inheritance tree, or only of a single class for the entire tree?

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that though. Unfortunately that would make my class inappropriately long - and I think I'd have to make the Parent a static inner...

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?  There might be a better design to use than to try to force each subclass to be a singleton.

Comment: @Jonathan A single instance of each class in the inheritance tree.

@jzd This is just to stay loyal to the State Pattern, and there are parts of existing code (   =[    ) which are dependant upon the fact that the instance of Child that they see is the only one.

Comment: @Dartoxian: In that case, my `enum` solution is just what the doctor ordered. :-) `enum`s are perfect for representing states in a state machine, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the set of your child classes fixed? If so, consider using an `enum`.

```
public enum Parent {
    CHILD1 {
        // class definition goes here
    },

    CHILD2 {
        // class definition goes here
    };

    // common definitions go here
}
```

Since the OP mentioned about state pattern, here are two examples of `enum`-based state machines: [a simple one](http://codepad.org/JGNCMzFF) and [a complex one](https://gist.github.com/cky/3392271).

Comment: Set of childs I expect to be very large and to grow

Comment: @Dartoxian: Right, but does it need to grow at runtime, or are you allowed to recompile? If the latter, this is still suitable.

Comment: Yeah recompile is what'll happen. Thanks for the link - it looks like a very useful pointer =]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but I don't see the point.  You would be better off using an enum IMHO.

```
enum {
  Singleton, 
  Child { /* override methods here * }
}
```

However to answer you question, you could do the following

```
class SingletonParent {
   private static final Set<Class> classes = new CopyOnArraySet();
   { if (!classes.add(getClass()) throw new AssertionError("One "+getClass()+" already created."); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong design pattern.

Take a look at the Factory pattern.  A factory can create a single instance of a class and then hand it out to anyone who wants it.  The factory can hand out a singleton of the parent, any child, or anything else you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java `enum`.  Basically it makes a bunch of public static classes (like you do) but puts a few restrictions on them.

```
public enum Child {
   INSTANCE;
}
```

Note that `enums` are full classes, so you can easily add methods on a per-instance basis if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer with a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304638/should-a-parent-class-ever-reference-child-classes) I asked a while back that was very similar. I believe that this will do what you want it to do, but comes with all the restrictions mentioned in the answers.